# How to perform a rails migration with dynamically generated sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations, pg

I'm trying to run either a `PG::Connection or a ActiveRecord::Base.connection` via interpreting some txt file during a rails migration. Seems like the migration runs out of memory pretty fast. Much faster than when I run a `PG::Connection` in just a ruby script. What is the cause of this?

```
def import_movies(db_conn)
  title_re = /^(#{$title}) \s+ \([0-9]+\) \s+ ([0-9]+)$/ix
    i = 0

    db_conn.transaction do |conn|
  # ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do # tried this also, slow
        stmt = prepare2(conn, "INSERT INTO movies (title, year) VALUES (?, ?);")

    File.new("#{DUMP_PATH}/movies.list").each_line do |line|
      print "." if (i = i + 1) % 5000 == 0; STDOUT.flush
      if match = title_re.match(line)
        stmt.execute!(match[1], match[2].to_i)
      end
        end
    end

    puts
end
```

Comment: are you running the script locally?

Comment: Would probably be faster to do this: `INSERT INTO movies (title, year) VALUES ('Blah', 1989), ('Blargh', 1990), ...`

Comment: @adaam thanks that will hlep me in the long run, mean while the currently problem seems to be that the db_conn.transaction seems to roll back without an apparent error. So non of the movies are getting created at all.